# Weak reference callback is not called because of circular references

Tags: python, lambda, weak-references

I'm trying to write a finalizer for Python classes that have circular references. I found out that weak reference callbacks are the [way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935153/del-method-being-called-in-python-when-it-is-not-expected). Unfortunately, it seems the lambda I use as a callback is never called. For example, running this code:

```
def del_A(name):
    print('An A deleted:' + name)

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print('A created')
        self.name = name
        self._wr = weakref.ref(self, lambda wr, n = self.name: del_A(n))

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('B created')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A('a1')
    b = B()
    a.other = b
    b.other = a
```

returns:

```
A created
B created
```

Removing the circular reference makes the lambda callback works ('An A deleted: a1' is printed). Replacing the lambda by a simple function call works too, but the parameter value is fixed when initializing the weak reference, and not when calling the callback:

```
self._wr = weakref.ref(self, del_A(self.name))
...
a = A('a1')
a.name = 'a2'
b = B()
a.other = b
b.other = a
```

returns:

```
A created
An A deleted:a1
B created
```

Any idea why the lambda callback does not work with circular references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I finally found the reason why the callback is not called in the presence of a weak reference:

Weak reference callbacks are not called if the ["weakref object dies before the object it
references"](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-November/040289.html)

It seems that when circular references are deleted, the weak reference attribute of class A is deleted before the callback has a chance to be called. One solution, is to append the finalizer (i.e., the weak reference and its callback) to a list of finalizers. For example:

```
def del_A(name):
    print('An A deleted:' + name)

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name, finalizers):
        print('A created')
        self.name = name
        finalizers.append(weakref.ref(self, lambda wr, n = self.name: del_A(n)))

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('B created')

def do_work(finalizers):
    a = A('a1', finalizers)
    b = B()
    a.other = b
    b.other = a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    finalizers = []
    do_work(finalizers)
```

will print:

```
A created
B created
An A deleted:a1
```

Note that do_work() is necessary, otherwise finalizers gets deleted before the callbacks have a chance to be called. Obviously, finalizers has to be managed properly to avoid building a huge list of weak references, but this is another issue.

Answer (score 3):

When you use

```
 self._wr = weakref.ref(self, lambda wr, n = self.name: del_A(n))
```

the callback will only be called when `self` is about to be finalized.

The reason why the callback is not getting called is because

```
a = A('a1')
b = B()
a.other = b   # This gives a another attribute; it does not switch `a` away from the original `a`
b.other = a
```

does not cause `a` to be finalized. The original `a` still exists.

The callback would be called if you changed the code to

```
a = A('a1')
b = B()
a = b
b = a
```

When you use

```
self._wr = weakref.ref(self, del_A(self.name))
```

then your callback is `None`. `del_A(self.name)` is not a reference to a function, it is a function call itself. So `del_A(self.name)` prints `An A deleted:a1` immediately (before `a1` is really finalized), and returns with the value `None`, which becomes the default callback for the weakref.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should clarify the wording of my question. I am aware that a.other = b does not switch a, but I would expect that at the end of the code block, a and b become out of scope and are thus garbage collected/finalized. Why is the lambda callback not called then? When I remove the circular reference, the lambda callback is called, which puzzles me.

Comment: But your explanation of why self._wr = weakref.ref(self, del_A(self.name)) does not work is right. del_A() is a function call, not a reference, so it is not the proper way of passing a callback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Circular references are cleaned up automatically. There are a few exceptions, such as classes that define a `__del__` method.

Usually you do not need to define a `__del__` method

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I believe it does not answer my problem. I use weak references to avoid __del__ methods.