# What's the Pythonic way to write an auto-closing class?

Tags: python

I'm a noob with Python, but I've written an auto-close function like this..

```
@contextmanager
def AutoClose(obj):
    try:
        yield obj
    finally:
        obj.Close()
```

I have three classes that have a Close() method that this function can be used with.  Is this the most Pythonic solution?  Should I be doing something in the classes themselves instead?

Comment: That seems good. You can also use a destructor in your class.

Comment: I would avoid using the destructor (i.e. `__del__`). It's really hard to reason about when/if it gets called. See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935153/del-method-being-called-in-python-when-it-is-not-expected

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're doing looks totally fine and Pythonic. Although, the `contextlib` standard library already has something similar, but you'll have to rename your `Close` methods to `close`.

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.closing(thing):
    print thing
```

I would recommend using this instead. After all, the recommended naming convention for Python methods is `all_lowercase_with_underscores`.

Comment: Note that 'bluedog' may also have to rename his (or her) .Close() method to .close() order to use contextlib.closing() (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: I have to keep the Close() method with current case, but I may add an alias called close() so that the standard contextlib.closing function can be used.

Answer (score 16):

Most pythonic solution is to define methods [`__enter__` and `__exit__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) methods in your class:

```
class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self, filename):
         self.filename = filename

     def __enter__(self):
         self.fd = open(self.filename)

     def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
         self.fd.close()
```

And using:

```
with Foo('/path/to/file') as foo:
    # do something with foo
```

Methods `__enter__` and `__exit__` will be implicitly called when entering and leaving blocks `with`. Also note that `__exit__` allows you to catch exception which raised inside the block `with`.

Function `contextlib.closing` is typically used for those classes that do not explicitly define the methods `__enter__` and `__exit__` (but have a method `close`). If you define your own classes, much better way is to define these methods.

Comment: +1 - This is an equally good answer IMO.  I have chosen @tom s answer because it is the solution I will use on this occasion.  The three particular classes all have a Close() method and have no requirement for \_\_enter\_\_, so the single auto_close function can be used for all three classes without touching the classes themselves.

Comment: your `__enter__` neglects to return something useful e.g. `self`. It took me ages to track down the problem.